# Unable to add ant design stylesheets with tailwind in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, antd, tailwind-css, esbuild, ruby-on-rails-7

I created a Rails 7 app using `rails new demo -j esbuild --css tailwind`.
I am using `antd` package for the components and want to use the ant design stylesheet along with the tailwind stylesheet.

Tailwind [has a way](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports) to add external stylesheets to its default styles. I used that and set `application.tailwind.css` file to this:

```js
@import "~antd/dist/antd.css";

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Now when I run `./bin/dev`, the `antd` styles are neither applied nor those style classes are present in the generated `app/assets/builds/application.css` file.

It looks like tailwind overwrites the ant design styles.

If I keep `application.tailwind.css` and add

```js
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

to my `index.js` root file, only then are the `antd` styles being applied and are present in the generated `app/assets/builds/application.css`. But then the tailwindcss classes are removed.

How can I have both ant design styles and tailwind styles together in the generated `app/assets/builds/application.css` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up linking my own stylesheets in Rails 7 with esbuild and TailwindCSS.

currently if you run `rails new demo --css tailwind` Rails will use the `tailwindcss-rails gem`

However, if you pass the javascript option like you've done with esbuild while creating the new app it will use the `cssbundling-rails gem` instead. `rails new demo -j esbuild --css tailwind`.

The documentation for the cssbundling-rails gem says

> If you want to use @import statements as part of your Tailwind
> application.js file, you need to configure Tailwind to use postcss and
> then postcss-import. **But you should also consider simply referring to
> your other CSS files directly, instead of bundling them all into one
> big file. It's better for caching, and it's simpler to setup. You can
> refer to other CSS files by expanding the stylesheet_link_tag in
> application.html.erb** like so: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application",
> "other", "styles", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>.

https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails#how-do-i-import-relative-css-files-with-tailwind

I created a new css file called `users` under `app/assets/stylesheets/users.css`

in `application.html.erb` I added the new `users` stylesheet after the `application` stylesheet in the `stylesheet_link_tag`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "users", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

in `app/assets/config/manifest.js` add `//= link users.css` after images and builds.

Comment: Thank you. This worked.