# How can I troubleshoot TailwindCss in my Rails 7 app to properly apply basic tailwind classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

A Rails7 app that used `-c tailwind` is not displaying the styles consistently when I try to do something basic like `border-5`.

I've started the app using `./bin/dev`

In the Procfile.dev is `css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch`

I've clobbered the assets, precompiled the assets, built the assets. Nothing.

I've tried every solution in this thread https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/160 However even DHH can't reproduce the error, and so I'm dubious about half of the solutions that seem to be working.

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462185/unable-to-add-ant-design-stylesheets-with-tailwind-in-rails-7) I'm wondering if I used esbuild for my javascript. Though I'm mentioning this as an aside, since it was about 3 months ago since I created this thing, and am not sure how to check my app for the javascript approach.

The actual inconsistency is really odd. If I apply, for example `<div class="border">` or `<div class="border-4">` the border appears.

If I try to use other completely permissible classes, such as `border-8`, nothing happens.

This suggests that there's something in the build, however that's a WAG (wild-ass guess) because I don't understand builds enough to confirm/deny.

My question is: What must be troubleshot in the app to make the tailwindcss classes work as expected?

Here are the specifics of the app.

```rb
# gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "3.1.4"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.2"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", ">= 4.0.1"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[windows jruby]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[mri windows]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"

  gem "error_highlight", ">= 0.4.0", platforms: [:ruby]
end

group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 6.1"
end

gem "tailwindcss-rails", "~> 2.0"

gem "rails_live_reload", "~> 0.3.4"

gem "view_component", "~> 3.7"

gem "pagy", "~> 6.2"

gem "devise", "~> 4.9"

gem "omniauth-github", "~> 2.0.0"

gem "figaro", "~> 1.2"

gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~> 1.0"

gem "rack-cors", "~> 2.0"

gem "dockerfile-rails", ">= 1.6", :group => :development
```

Here's the tailwind.config.js

```js
# config/tailwind.config.js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/components/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

Here's the application.css, for good measure:

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS (and SCSS, if configured) file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

and application.tailwind.css, as well:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Procfile, for good measure:

```bash
rails: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
```

Edit 1:
Now that I've taken the very deliberate step to run `rake tailwindcss:install`.... I find this task appends `manifest.js` with

```js
//= link_tree ../builds
```

And as I inspect the file at `app/assets/builds/tailwind.css`, I find that `border-4` is there, however, none of the other tailwind css classes are available.

So maybe I'm also curious about what the `build` task is doing...

Comment: you could run tailwind command directly: `tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -c config/tailwind.config.js`. compiled css will just print in the console. `border-5` is not a tailwind class, but `border-8` should show up. "none of the other tailwind css classes are available" - only classes that are present in your templates will show up.

Comment: thanks @Alex, Turns out I was attempting to use non-tailwind classes, and getting frustrated at my inability to properly read the documentation. It appears Tailwind is properly applying basic Tailwind classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue.

Looking through another project that does not exhibit this issue I noticed that I had an extra line in my \config\environments\development.rb config file.

```
  # Cause the tailwinds engine to rebuild style sheet
  config.assets.debug = true
```

Once I added this line to the config file, tailwinds compiles the css correctly.  I must have had this issue previously and completely forgotten as to how or why this seems to work.

Comment: thanks for reviewing my question, though this is a solution that's part of the thread related to the issue 160 over on github that I linked in my question. However, since this is working for some, and not others, there must be some reason why it's having success so I'm grateful for the response; Turns out, I was attempting to apply classes that aren't actual tailwind classes, and Tailwind apparently is compiling correctly.